# Batch auto answer "y" if registry key values exists

Tags: batch-file, registry, addition

I'm really not used to use batchs...So i'm stuck on a problem : I want to ADD some registry key values but it will prompt :

```
"key alreday exists, overwrite it (yes/no) ?"
```

So i would like to make `if key value exists echo y and press <enter>`

`else reg ADD` the value....

The fact is i am totally lost in writing batch files, i tried this but i don't know how to make the `IF` statement...And even less how to automatize the prompt answer !

```
@echo off

reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Patcher || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Patcher /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "Updater_Launcher_ENG.exe"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v PatchNum /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "184" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v PatchNum /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "184"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v IntegratedPak /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "projectg500+.pak" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v IntegratedPak /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "projectg500+.pak"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Ver /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "TH.R4.584.04" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Ver /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "TH.R4.584.04"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Install_Dir /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Pangya eXtremV2" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Install_Dir /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Pangya eXtremV2"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Argument /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "not_used" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Argument /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "not_used"

REG query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1" || REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in your subsequent answer, you should use the `/F` option with `Add` to force the overwriting of existing value data. Please open a Command Prompt window type `reg /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to read the usage information.

However, there were several other issues with what you've posted, so I have rewritten the entire thing for you in two possible formats, *(as I was unsure of your true intention)*.

Please note that I have made several, more appropriate, changes to what you posted, please do not modify any of the content I have posted, it has been written using the correct syntax, keys, values and data. Please also remember that this code is adding to a protected area of the Windows registry, so you must be running this script elevated or as a user with the required permissions.

---

This is how I'd suggest you perform the task, if you only want to add all of the registry keys, if there is already an existing value named `Patcher`:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ntreev\PangYa_Th"
Set "Reg=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"

%Reg% Query "%Key%" /Reg:32 /F "Patcher" /V 1> NUL 2>&1 && (
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Argument" /D "not_used" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Install_Dir" /D "\"C:\Pangya eXtremV2\"" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "IntegratedPak" /D "projectg500+.pak" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Launcher Version" /D "v3.1" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Patcher" /D "Updater_Launcher_ENG.exe" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "PatchNum" /D "184" /F 1> NUL
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Ver" /D "TH.R4.584.04" /F 1> NUL
)
```

---

If you simply want to add all of the data regardless of any existing values, then just this would be all you need:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ntreev\PangYa_Th"
Set "Reg=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"

%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Argument" /D "not_used" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Install_Dir" /D "\"C:\Pangya eXtremV2\"" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "IntegratedPak" /D "projectg500+.pak" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Launcher Version" /D "v3.1" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Patcher" /D "Updater_Launcher_ENG.exe" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "PatchNum" /D "184" /F 1> NUL
%Reg% Add "%Key%" /Reg:32 /V "Ver" /D "TH.R4.584.04" /F 1> NUL
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `/F` at `Patcher` line :) However i will use your second solution ! Thank you !

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I've now fixed that typo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after trying so many complicated solutions, i found out in the doc **how to overwrite without prompt**...

```
/f  Adds the registry entry without prompting for confirmation.
```

So it's ok i have this working good :

```
@echo off
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Patcher /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "Updater_Launcher_ENG.exe" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v PatchNum /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "184" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v IntegratedPak /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "projectg500+.pak" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Ver /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "TH.R4.584.04" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Install_Dir /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Pangya eXtremV2" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Argument /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "not_used" /f
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ntreev\PangYa_Th /v Launcher Version /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "v3.1" /f
```

Comment: source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add

Comment: Please take time to read, my posted solutions, _(based upon this posted answer, I'm assuming you only needed the lower of my two examples)_ .What mine does, is use the appropriate syntax to add the registry data to the correct location on both a x86 or x64 bit system, uses the correct data type, _(the default of REG_SZ)_, correctly encloses your path with spaces, in doublequotes, and prevents output of any 'success' messages.